# Are we allowed to watch the NCAA tournament games in their entirety this year (2016)?

Tags: basketball, collegiate, media

In previous years, I remember being able to watch all NCAA tournament basketball games in their entirety, even after the game had ended.  However, this year, it seems like it's only showing a recap and not showing the full game.

Did things change when I wasn't paying attention or is there a way to watch the full game after it has ended on the ncaa's website [(link to site here)](http://www.ncaa.com/march-madness-live)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for NCAA customer support and will be out of date within a year.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, i can delete if the mods think it should be.  I have no problems with that.